# Combining Cyber Implant Weapons and Martial Arts?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

Can you combine a cyber implant weapon (Handblade, SR5458) with a martial art? The handblade is using the Unarmed Combat skill and the Physical limit.

So if anybody knows something about that...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but whether a certain technique can be used with a specific cyber implant weapon is a GM decision. E.g. no grappling techniques with a Handblade (see the *Run & Gun*, red box, p. 136; Blades are mentioned).

Furthermore there is a Martial Arts style that relies on Cyber Implants: *Sangre y Acero* (*Run & Gun*, p. 133)